# ValueError: arrays must all be same length in python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

When running the below code I'm getting the following error:

```
error msg :"ValueError: arrays must all be same length". tfl_stops.txt : 490000235Z, 490010131WB ,490000112M...
```

```py
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import json

temp = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()

with open("tfl_stops.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
   fileList = [line.strip() for line in file]
for ids in fileList:
   r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/StopPoint/' + ids + '?includeCrowdingData=true')
   r = r.text
   temp = pd.read_json(r)
   df = pd.concat([df, temp], sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('stop_loc.csv')
```

> Question: Is there something wrong with my code or the format of my text file?

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: I shared error message